# How to declare a constant datatype using a class property datatype in typescript?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typescript-class

I'm creating a nestjs API so I'm using classes to declare my entities for example

```
export class Customer {
id: number;
name: string;
}
```

So now I'm working in my Customer Controller and I would like to type an get query param as customer.id because I'm thinking if some day the customer id data type changes to string automatically making my controller query param as string too.

```
@GET()
getCustomerById(@Params('id', id: Customer.id)) {
return this.customerService.getCustomerById(id))
}
```

Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TypeScript lookup types:

```
getCustomerById(@Params('id') id: Customer['id']) {}
```